Kendo UI Grid Layout incorrect
We used to successfully compile custom sass with kendo-theme-bootstrap version 5.4.1, but when we updated to version 6.7.0 even the latest version the grid layout all incorrect.
incorrect grid layout image
We tried using the “all.css” from the kendo-theme-bootstrap dist folder, but we found that neither its CSS styles nor the styles of my bundled CSS grid are correct. We would like to know if anyone has encountered similar issues and how to resolve it.

Seems like a stylesheet is completely missing. Also make sure the scripts version corresponds to the theme version.
